# cant install and use simple-qrcode package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web

I can,t install composer require simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode package

when i try to install simple-qrcode packege I get this errors,

[image: error image]

Comment: i suggest you use directly the original package `Bacon/BaconQrCode`

Comment: That's not an issue it's warning caused by the package not implementing PSR-4 Autoload Standard As my search on web i found https://packagist.org/packages/milon/barcode you can use it